# List and workflow.. how to solve it?

Tags: list, workflow

I am writing a list with some fields (Title, Status,... ). What I want to do now is: 
- The Status should only be changeable by a group of persons (maybe via a button) but now by all people who can see this task.

Should the "status" be a read only field and should I make another field that is changed by an workflow or how would you do this? How can a workflow only be active/visible to some persons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about is column-level security, and it's not doable with SharePoint without creative custom coding. Anyone who can edit list items in that list can edit that field. You could customize the UI to disable the control or something of that nature, but clever users will always find a way around it.

You enable content approval(in advanced settings) or you can lock the list down for edits altogether. Alternately you can look into a workflow to set that status.

Answer (score 1):

What version of SharePoint are you using. If it is SharePoint 2010 with Enterprise features and therefore InfoPath Forms Services you can do something. Its not exactly easy so my question would be how familiar are you InfoPath and using the SharePoint Web services within infopath. The gist of this is you could create your list and then customize in InfoPath. You would add a reference to the Groups web service and then check to see if the user is in the correct SharePoint security group. The status field would be hidden unless the current user exists in the appropriate SharePoint group.

Does this give you enough information to start from? Keep in mind that this will not lock down the field from a datasheet view.